# How to read this json file directly from github in Python with urllib3?

Tags: json, python-3.x, github, urllib3

I'm trying to import a particular json file from github with

```
import urllib3
import json
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/BigData/main/fr-esr-principaux-etablissements-enseignement-superieur.json'
f = http.request('GET', url)
data = json.load(f.data)
```

Could you please explain why there is below error and how to read this file correctly?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-cc9b55b171d7> in <module>
      4 url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/BigData/main/fr-esr-principaux-etablissements-enseignement-superieur.json'
      5 f = http.request('GET', url)
----> 6 data = json.load(f.data)

~\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in load(fp, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    291     kwarg; otherwise ``JSONDecoder`` is used.
    292     """
--> 293     return loads(fp.read(),
    294         cls=cls, object_hook=object_hook,
    295         parse_float=parse_float, parse_int=parse_int,

AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `urllib3` I would recommend the more modern `requests` library.
Your code could look like this:

```
import requests
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/BigData/main/fr-esr-principaux-etablissements-enseignement-superieur.json'
f = requests.get(url)
# The .json() method automatically parses the response into JSON.
data = f.json()
```

If you want to use urllib3, the data must be decoded, and the json loads (not load) method should be used. For example:

```
import urllib3
import json
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/BigData/main/fr-esr-principaux-etablissements-enseignement-superieur.json'
f = http.request('GET', url)
data = json.loads(f.data.decode("utf8"))
```

Comment: Your method works, but I'm still curious about how to solve the problem with `urllib3`.